# Test-retest reliability for a test taken twice but with a variable delay between tests

Tags: correlation, clustering, repeated-measures, descriptive-statistics, reliability

I have a dataset that is composed of a few thousand datapoints, each of which consists of two test results for a participant that were collected when they underwent the test at Time A and Time B. The problem is that the interval between the first and second test attempt is variable between participants. In other words, participant 1 repeated the test after 6 days (Time Difference=6d), participant 2 repeated the test after 361 days (TD=361), participant 3 repeated it after 1803 days (TD=1803), and so on.

| Participant | Date of Attempt 1 | Date of Attempt 2 | Time Difference | Result Attempt 1 | Result Attempt 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan. 2nd, 2001 | Jan. 7th, 2001 | 5 days | 6.321 | 6.322 |
| 2 | Oct. 17th, 2006 | Feb. 11th, 2008 | 482 days | 2.444 | 2.675 |
| 3 | Mar. 23rd, 2009 | Jan. 16th, 2015 | 2125 days | 1.432 | 2.444 |

As far as I understand, what I need to do first is to group this data by time difference - in other words chunk the data as follows:

- Group A (TD = x days to y days)
- Group B (TD = y+1 days to z+1 days)
- ... and so on

Where I am stuck is answering the question of what methodology I can use to determine what specific time difference chunks I should use?

In other words, if I want to decide that:

- Group A = (TD = 7 days to 31 days)
- Group B = (TD = 32 days to 70 days)
- Group C = (TD = 71 days to 165 days)

What methodology can I use to justify said grouping?

The intent behind this is to determine test-retest stability (test results do not change with time). Unfortunately, every single study that I have found tests for this using **set and not variable** time delays. Put another way, they generally test **all** participants at time A and then re-test them at time B and use this to prove that a test is reliable over time. In my case, however, all participants underwent the test for a first time at different points in time and then re-did the test again for a second time likewise at different times, which results in varying and non-constant time delays between test attempts.

Any advice that anyone could offer would be appreciated as I am really stumped. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you think the test-retest reliability varies depending on time between test and retest? If so, that’s going to require some serious time series/latent growth curve modeling.

Comment: Are the questions on an interval scale (precise measurements) or an ordinal scale (like a Likert scale)?

Comment: That being said, there’s no justification, scientifically or statistically speaking, for grouping the test-takers into just 3 categories in the way you describe. Doing so will give incorrect results.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I believe there is reason to think that test-retest reliability may vary depending on the time-between. Could you please provide me with some guidance which I could follow to get started? The questions are on a Likert scale.

Comment: Sorry about the vagueness on that point - I am not planning to group the test-takers into just 3 categories specifically. However, I do not know how many categories there will be.

Comment: @ClosedLimelikeCurves Sorry to disturb you - not sure what the proper procedure is here - but I would very much appreciate any advice you may have to offer.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, I've been a bit busy.

The main thing I suggest taking a look at is a book by Richard McElreath called Statistical Rethinking. This book includes sections on dealing with ordinal data like Likert scales. Are you familiar with any probabilistic programming languages?

Comment: Hi, of course no worries, I just wasn’t sure if I had to tag you in order for you to get notified. I will definitely take a look, thank you for the tip! I’m afraid I am not - but I will likely be taking a look into R, if that is one of them.

Comment: R is a statistical programming language rather than a probabilistic one. While related, the two are a bit different. Examples of PPLs would be Turing.jl, PyMC3, or Stan. Statistical Rethinking goes over how to use these in depth.

Comment: Ah, great, that sounds perfect then. I will be sure to have a read ASAP. Thanks again!

Comment: I've laid out the broad strokes of a model that should work well in a response. If you need help or you're having trouble, you can contact me [here](https://github.com/TuringLang/Turing.jl). I also know of a reading group for Statistical Rethinking starting soon; you can find it [here](https://discord.gg/m9x9tR3u).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and all of your help! I will be certain to check out that book and I will be in touch when I make some progress in terms of reading and researching into this. Thanks again - much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put together the major strokes of a model. Unfortunately, I don't know of any stats packages that implement this model, so you'd need to code it yourself. I recommend *Statistical Rethinking* by Richard McElreath for a great introduction to how to build your own statistical models and program them in a PPL like Turing or Stan.

The model I'd suggest is a random walk on a latent variable. This model will go something like this:

- You have an underlying latent variable that's normally distributed. (This is the same as a probit model.)
- We have a set of "cutpoints" as in the ordered probit (or logistic) regression that need to be estimated. McElreath discusses how to implement an ordered logistic regression in his book.
- The latent Gaussian variable for each participant follows an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process, a Gaussian process with an exponential kernel. (This sounds fancy, but don't worry -- it's not as complicated as it sounds, and Statistical Rethinking goes over Gaussian processes well).

Comment: Hello again! I am desperately stuck, I am afraid. I read through as much of the book as possible and found that Chapter 14 was most applicable to my case. However, I found myself completely lost as to how to estimate the 'cutpoints.' Basically, I cannot figure out how to cluster the time-differences into groups which, as far as I understand, are then fed into the Gaussian process. Perhaps what I am confused about is what the underlying latent variable is? If you could walk me through each step that I need to do in more detail, it would be immensely appreciated! @ClosedLimelikeCurves